# JavaScript How can I get a value and put in it into function

Tags: javascript, function, this

You can check my all of my codes in this [Link](https://github.com/sangumee/Udacity-Classic-Arcade-Game)

and there are demo with github pages [Link](https://sangumee.github.io/Udacity-Classic-Arcade-Game/)

Now, I make it when I start game, I can see game environment. But I want to make it choose the character that I want.

So I use VEX Libaray to use dialog that asks what Character . You can check my screenshot. 
[image]

So I make it when I click each buttons it can print like this.

[image]

After that Only I have to do is I should put a value to this.sprite. But I don't know How can I put it into Player.

[image]

and the core code are here.

```
// To choose Character with VEX Library
function click1() {
    vex.dialog.open({
        message: 'Which character do you want to play?',
        buttons: [
            $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
                className: 'vex-dialog-button-primary-horizontal',
                text: 'Char-Boy',
                click: function (e) {
                    this.value = 'char-boy';
                    this.close();
                }
            }),
            $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
                className: 'vex-dialog-button-primary-horizontal',
                text: 'Char-Cat-Girl',
                click: function (e) {
                    this.value = 'char-cat-girl';
                    this.close();
                }
            }),
            $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
                className: 'vex-dialog-button-primary-horizontal',
                text: 'Char-Horn-Girl',
                click: function (e) {
                    this.value = 'char-horn-girl';
                    this.close();
                }
            }),
            $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
                className: 'vex-dialog-button-primary-horizontal',
                text: 'Char-Pink-Girl',
                click: function (e) {
                    this.value = 'char-pink-girl';
                    this.close();
                }
            }),
            $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
                className: 'vex-dialog-button-primary-horizontal',
                text: 'Char-Princess-Girl',
                click: function (e) {
                    this.value = 'char-princess-girl';
                    this.close();
                }
            })
        ],
        callback: function (value) {
            // char-boy','char-cat-girl','char-horn-girl','char-pink-girl','char-princess-girl
            if (value === 'char-boy') {
                console.log('You choose Char-boy');
                return value;
            } else if (value === 'char-cat-girl') {
                console.log('You choose Char-Cat-Girl');
                return value;
            } else if (value === 'char-horn-girl') {
                console.log('you choose Char-Horn-Girl');
                return value;
            } else if (value === 'char-pink-girl') {
                console.log('You Choose Char-Pink-Girl');
                return value;
            } else if (value === 'char-princess-girl') {
                console.log('You Choose Char-Princess-Girl');
                return value;
            } else {
                console.log('Choose Nothing');
                return value;
            }
        }
    })
}

let Player = function (x, y, speed, value) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.sprite = 'images/' + value + '.png';
};
```

Comment: You might want to read about `switch...case` construct in Javascript.

Comment: Show the part of the code that creates the **player**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you create a new instance of Player later on when initializing the game so maybe you could Player's prototype to set the value, like this:

```
let Player = function (x, y, speed) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.speed = speed;
   this.sprite = 'images/' + this.value + '.png';
};
Player.prototype.value = 'char-boy'; // this should go inside vex callback
console.log(new Player(50,50,100).sprite); // this should print "images/char-boy.png"
```

Attaching a reference to the documentation about Prototype: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp

Comment: Thanks for the help. I should check object prototype part.